# When $x$ is divided by $y$, and $x$ is not divisible by $y$, what is the maximum number of decimal places?

Tags: number-theory

Somewhere (I will provide reference once I remember where I got this statement from), I read that:

> *"When $x$ is divided by $y$, and the resulting number is a decimal *, then the maximum number of recurring digits in the result is $(y-1)$ "*
>
> *Definition of **decimal**: *A number in the form of $a$, or in other words, a constant. Examples: 1.23 or 3.63 or 28... etc.*

I have found this true for many values of $\frac{x}{y}$.

Examples:

$1/2 = 0.5$ The recurring digits is 5

$1/3 = 0.\overline3$ The recurring digit is 3

$1/7 = 0.\overline{142857}$ The recurring digits are 142857

$1/11 = 0.\overline{09}$ The recurring digits are 09.

The statement is true at the moment because $2>1, 3>1, 7>6, 11>2$

Is there a good algebraic proof for this?

Comment: Hint:  If you divide x/y you get a remainder.  Then when you divide the y into the remainder you get another remainder.  Ask yourself:  How many possible different remainders are there? and What happens if I come across a remainder a second time?

Comment: @fleablood, give me an example.

Comment: If you divide 317/257  You get 1 with a remainder of 60.  So you have to divide 600 by 256 and you get 2 and  a remainder of 86.  How many possible remainders are there?  What would happen if you ever get a remainder of 60 again?  What would you do next?  What would be the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what it means to compute $x/y$ in decimal using long division. You have your remainder, $r_{i-1}$, from the previous digit calculation. You then "drop down a zero" to get $10r_{i-1}$ and divide by $y$; the quotient
$$\left\lfloor \frac{10r_{i-1}}{y}\right\rfloor$$
becomes the next digit, and you also calculate a new remainder $r_i = 10r_{i-1}\bmod y$.

Notice that this process depends *only on the previous remainder* $r_{i-1}$. As soon as you hit a remainder $r_i$ that matches some remainder $r_{\mathrm{prev}}$ that you have seen before, you will have $r_{i+1} = r_{\mathrm{prev}+1}$, etc, so that the decimal digits will start to repeat.

How long can you go without repeating? The maximum number of distinct remainders you can get when dividing by $y$, which is $y$ itself. The reason that the period is at most $y-1$ digits long, and not $y$, is that if you ever hit zero as a remainder, the long division terminates and you do not get a repeating decimal at all; therefore the set of possible remainders you can encounter while computing the repeating part of a decimal expansion is just the $y-1$ numbers $\{1,\ldots,y-1\}$.